# how do you access chatter public links through apex/api?

Tags: force.com-sites, chatter-file

On a chatter file you have the option to share it with a public link by going to file sharing settings -> share via link. You get a link of the form:

```
https://cs10.salesforce.com/sfc/p/J00000006xkGRrSFndEnKTJ.makAJDKKerg9naQ=
```

Is there a way to create these links via apex/api and then query for the link URL?

My use case is creating these links for 4-5 chatter files (that are not all related to the same record) and sending out an email with them.

Comment: Have you looked at Chatter Connect? This page (look at FileSummary option) might give you the link you want http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/index_Left.htm#CSHID=connect_resources_how_to.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fconnect_resources_how_to.htm|SkinName=webhelp

Comment: Assuming that the "DownloadURL" there is the same url as in the chatter REST api I don't think this is exactly what I need. That url is of the form '/services/data/chatter/files...' which is different from the public sharing link that SF gives you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Winter 15 it's even easier, you can use Content Distribution :
https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentdistribution.htm

Answer (score 5):

As sharing chatter files via the link is based on content deliveries, I suspect you can't do this. I spent some considerable time investigating the creation of content deliveries programmatically and was unable to find an API to access.

There's an idea for this at:

http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KaQoAAK

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to get the share url through the chatter rest api:

/services/data/v30.0/chatter/files/[fileId]/file-shares/link/

See the chatter rest api pdf for more details..