# How to add download functionality for related Files of a particular object record on custom VF Site page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites, files, contentdocument

On Salesforce standard page for a particular record, all related Notes, Attachments and Files are shown under "*Notes & Attachments section*".

I have a similar use case where, where on a VF site page:

1. I am displaying some fields for particular object's record.
2. Successfully added download option for all related Attachments.
3. Successfully added download/display option for all related Notes.

**However I am not able to display and add download option for related Files.**

**How to access related files in Apex/VF?**

**How to add file download link on site page for external user?**

**Is there any configuration/access permission needs to be granted for site guest user?**

Answer (score 1):

**However I am not able to display and add download option for related Files.**

Files are called Content Document, and theier links to record is called ContentDocumentLink. You have to querry the ContentDocumentLink by providing for which record you want those

**How to access related files in Apex/VF?**

```
Select id,ContentDocumentId From ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId=:YOUR_RECORD_ID
```

**How to add file download link on site page for external user?**
If the internal user has made that file as public accessible, then the file link will be stored in contentDistribution.

```
Select Id, DistributionPublicUrl  FROM ContentDistribution WHERE ContentDocumentId = contentDocumentID
```

DistributionPublicUrl is the public URL for that file.

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000g1ClIAI

Comment: Hi Pranay, Thanks for your inputs! I tried same SOQL from anonymous window/workbench (with admin profile), then it is returning me result list. However, for some reason, when I tried same SOQL in site page's controller, then it is returning empty list.  Also i tried same URL but in return it is showing error 'top.location={{instance}}/ex/errorduringprocessing.jsp'.  Is there any configuration/access issue for site guest user?

Comment: Can you make your apex class as without sharing?

Comment: Yes! controller is already without sharing. SOQL still returning empty list

Comment: Hi Pranay, Regarding "DistributionPublicUrl  -- ContentDistribution", as per my observations and some other answers references [https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1625/how-do-you-access-chatter-public-links-through-apex-api/44055], we are not able to create "ContentDistribution" or "ContentDielivery" programmatically. It only gets created when you manually created and share public link,